# How do you perform find/replace in selected text with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a C file I am editing with Notepad++, and there is a section of about 30 consecutive lines where I want to replace one word with another word. Is there a way to do a Find/Replace All with Notepad++ on only that section?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an 'In Selection' checkbox in the Notepad++ Find/Replace dialog, right next to the 'Replace All' button. Use that and you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: But it's only in `replace` tab, not `find` tab

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: the OP wanted to replace stuff, only searching within a selection is irrelevant.

Comment: It's grayed out in my case, and I have selected a subset of the text. What am I missing?

Comment: @Divan: hard to say. Did you select the text before opening the find dialog? It only seems to test for text being selected when it opens, not afterwards. Maybe that solves your problem?

Comment: @phuclv: FYI at some point the in selection checkbox was also added to the find tab in a recent version of Notepad++

Comment: this seems to only work for horizontal line selections, not vertical ones using the Alt key.

Answer (score 2):

The "In Selection" checkbox is a bit finicky. It doesn't always work on the first attempt. I have to repeat the cycle "Select:Search Replace:Close if checkbox greyed out". I am able to check the box on 2nd or 3rd attempt.

Also, it doesn't work when selection is done in Column Mode. Many times I just want to replace text in certain columns. But it's always greyed out when text selected in column mode.