# How to Find and Replace in the Marked Lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I want to find and replace in only marked lines in Notepad++. How can I do that?

Example :

I marked lines(containing XYZ) of following text with using Find&Replace - Mark tab. After marking, I want to replace "PROBLEM" word with another word in only lines which I marked.

```
XYZ THIS IS A SAMPLE TO EXPLAIN MY PROBLEM.
SAMPLE TO EXPLAIN MY PROBLEM
XYZ EXPLAIN TO MY PROBLEM
MY PROBLEM
XYZ PROBLEM
```

Or how can I select/highlight the marked lines. If I found this feature, my problem will be solved (with IN SELECTION option).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you perform find/replace in selected text with Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110666/how-do-you-perform-find-replace-in-selected-text-with-notepad)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But It works only for selected words. I want to mark specific lines with Search Box  - Mark tab and theb find&replace in only these marked lines.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But, you don't need to Mark the lines first and then Find/Replace on those lines. You can do it in single step. It seems you are solving XY problem. Edit your question with sample file data and the expected outcome.

Comment: Exactly, how are you marking the 3rd and 5th lines? What is the criteria for marking?

Comment: I mark lines with searching a specific word. But imagine that I mark 3rd and 5th lines manual in this sample.

Comment: I think question is very clear. There is a screenshoot what I want to say. I marked lines which have XYZ word with using MARK LINE feature. Now I want to find PROBLEM word and replace it with new word in only marked lines. : http://image.prntscr.com/image/88bb1a45042f4abe980b208da324be83.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this without having to mark the lines first. 
Keep the Search Mode as Regular Expression.

1. If you want to replace PROBLEM in all lines ***starting with XYZ***.

   - Search for `^(XYZ.*)PROBLEM` and Replace it with `\1SOLVED`
2. If ***XYZ is not at the start***.

   - Search for `^(.*XYZ.*)PROBLEM` and Replace it with `\1SOLVED`
3. If ***XYZ can appear after PROBLEM***.

   - Search for `((.*XYZ.*)(PROBLEM))|((PROBLEM)(.*XYZ.*))` and Replace it with `\2CHANGED\6`

Comment: What would be the RegEx if I want to search and replace in the all lines EXCEPT the ones containing XYZ?