# notepad++ Stop replacing at a specific line

Tags: replace, notepad++

I've been trying to figure something out for a while now and I can't seem to understand. I've looked everywhere and I still can't find it.

I'm trying to make a dictionary for an auto corrector with AutoHotKey and I need to replace the beginning of each line with "::" and somewhere in between the line with another "::" 
like so: 
`::togehter::together`
Now I have around 20,000 of these to add with no "::" yet and what I'm doing is this in the replace textbox:

```
Replace: ^
With: ::
```

Now it works fine for the first line BUT if I press replace all cause no way am I going to click 20,000 times on replace, it replaces not only from where I am to the bottom but also the beginning too. So every line now has a new "::" added.

So what I need is to be able to tell the replace at what line to stop instead of doing every single line.

Also if you could help me add the "::(word)" after the first ::(misspelled word) that would be a great help.

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiJJS.png)

Comment: Please, edit your question and add some sample lines and expected result.

Comment: You could paste the set of lines that you need the replacement in, into a new file buffer.  Do the Replace All only in this new buffer. After the replacement you copy/paste the subset of lines back into the original file. This works as long as your subset of lines is one consecutive block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you perform find/replace in selected text with Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110666/how-do-you-perform-find-replace-in-selected-text-with-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the regular expression replace-all of `^` with some text, i.e. to add some text at the start of every line, does not work in some versions of Notepad++. My workaround for this was to use the `^(.)` as the search string and include `\1` in the replacement. For your case the replacement would be `::\1`. The effect here is to replace the first character of each line with `::` plus the first character. In a quick test with Notepad++ v7.1, replacing `^` with `::` worked as I would want.

Two things should be checked in the Replace dialogue before doing the replace-all: (1) that "Regular expression" is selected and (2) "In selection" is not  selected.

The question is not clear how the two words in the input are separated, so assuming that one or more spaces or tabs is used the search string to use is `^(\w+)\h+` and the replace string is `::\1::`.

Answer (score 0):

This AutoHotkey script might do what you require.
It leaves unchanged lines that start with '::',
and prepends/replaces text in the others. You copy the original text to the clipboard, run this script, and then the desired text is put on the clipboard. (To create and run the script: copy and paste it into a text editor and save it as myscriptname.ahk, or myscriptname.txt and then drag and drop the file into the AutoHotkey exe file. Or alternatively, if you save it as an ahk file, and install AutoHotkey, you can double-click to run.) [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/)

```
vText := Clipboard
vOutput := ""
VarSetCapacity(vOutput, StrLen(vText)*2*2)
StringReplace, vText, vText, `r`n, `n, All
Loop, Parse, vText, `n
{
vTemp := A_LoopField

if (vTemp = "")
if (1, vOutput .= "`r`n")
continue

if (SubStr(vTemp, 1, 2) = "::")
if (1, vOutput .= vTemp "`r`n")
continue

StringReplace, vTemp, vTemp, %A_Space%, ::, All
vOutput .= "::" vTemp "`r`n"
}
Clipboard := vOutput
MsgBox done
Return
```

Comment: What language is this script? How would the question asker run it? How would they run it direct from Notepad++?

Comment: Fair point, the questioner mentioned 'AutoHotkey', but yes I will amend my answer, to make it more useful to others.