# Can I search for something in notepad++ between a specific set of lines?

Tags: notepad++

Can I search for something in notepad++ between a specific set of lines ? example: search for 'progress' between lines 1200 to 1800?

Comment: Copy the lines you want to search in in a new file and search for what you want in the new file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it isn't exactly what you're looking for, you can search in selection.
So highlight lines 1200 to 1800 and search your thing.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrMNx.jpg]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110685/3244407

Answer (score 0):

Select the text you want in the notepad++. 
Use **Inselection** checkbox in the Replace tab[image]